# Cannot install any google cloud modules using NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

Running `npm install @google-cloud/speech` gives:

```
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://github.com/google-cloud/speech)
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git@github.com:google-cloud/speech)
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Animesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-google-cloud-speech-00c2e0cb'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install google-cloud/speech
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'E:\WebstormProjects\live-delfoi-speech-demo\google-cloud\speech'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@google-cloud/speech"
npm ERR! cwd E:\WebstormProjects\live-delfoi-speech-demo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! path E:\WebstormProjects\live-delfoi-speech-demo\google-cloud\speech
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\WebstormProjects\live-delfoi-speech-demo\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0`
```

The official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/speech) say that I have the use that same command to install the specified version.

How can I correct it?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the git repository has been moved to `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your node version. You need to upgrade your node from 0.10 to some latest and stable version.